# Flutter appbundle building using older version

Tags: flutter, google-play-console

I want to upload the second version of my Flutter app to the internal test channel on Google Play (I am just working with the Android version for now).

I could upload the first version `1.0.0+1` but when trying to upload the second version `1.0.1+2` Google Play Console is rejecting my appbundle with error message

`You need to use a different version code for your APK because you already have one with version code 1`.

I have already tried the sequence:

`flutter clean` to delete build and temp folders.

Modifying `version` line on `pubspec.yaml` from `1.0.0+1` to `1.0.1+2`.

`flutter pub get` to rebuild flutter needed files.

`flutter build appbundle` to get the bundle built.

Since I have been already able to build and publish the first version of the app I assume that the rest of the build configuration is OK.

Most of the solutions aim to clean project, modify `pubspec.yaml` and then rebuild but this seems not to be working for me.

**EDIT:**

tried to modify `build.gradle` file using values `flutterVersionName = '1.0.1'` and `flutterVersionCode = '2'` and I am still getting an appbundle with versionCode 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a workaround good enough and that is building the appbundle not using Flutter sdk, but using Android Studio.

In order to achieve that do the following:

**Open Android Studio > Open android project** (`android` folder in your Flutter project)

Then modify your app level `build.gradle` as follows:

```
defaultConfig {
    // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
    applicationId "<YOUR_APP_ID>"
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 28
    versionCode 2     // Manually add your desired version code
    versionName "1.0.1"      // Manually add your desired version name
//        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
//        versionName flutterVersionName
    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
```

Then go to **Build > Generate Signed Bundle / APK...** to generate your bundle or APK as if you were building a native app (further instructions to generate a signed app bundle can be found [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing#sign-apk)

*Please note that this **does not** fully solve the issue since the bundle still cannot be correctly generated using Flutter sdk.*

Answer (score 1):

Android app version code and version name are defined in `android/app/build.gradle`. Take a look at this file and check if these lines are included

```
...
def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}      

 def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}
...
 defaultConfig {
    applicationId "net.myapp"
    minSdkVersion 18
    targetSdkVersion 28
    versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger() //<-this line defines versionCode
    versionName flutterVersionName
...
```

If everything is ok, take a look at android/local.properties file. This file is updated when Flutter build the app. It should have these lines, generated from your pubspec.yaml data:

```
flutter.versionName=1.1.1
flutter.versionCode=9
```

If both files are ok, run a `flutter build apk` to regenerate local.properties data.

Comment: `build.gradle` is ok and `android/local.properties` is generated correctly indicating that both `versionName` and `versionCode` are the ones I intend to use. My issue comes when I try to upload the .aab to Play Console with the above error message.

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer prevents the version from being managed by flutter.

After changing the version you should run the `flutter pub upgrade`  command.